# Template function specialization for specific template ( not type )

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, partial-specialization

I have some templated class types like A,B,C as follows:

```
template < typename T >
class A{}; 

template < typename T >
class B{}; 

template < typename T >
class C{};
```

And now I want to have a function which accepts in general any type like:

```
template < typename T> 
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "Default " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

And now I want to specialize the function to only accept one of the given template classes like:

```
template < typename T>
void Func<A<T>>() 
{
    std::cout << "All A Types " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Which is not allowed because it is only a partial specialization. OK.

I think `concept` may help but it feels that I think much too complicated. My solution is:

```
template < typename T, template <typename > typename OUTER >
bool Check; 

template < typename INNER, template < typename > typename OUTER, template < typename> typename T>
constexpr bool Check< T<INNER>, OUTER > = std::is_same_v< OUTER<INNER>, T<INNER>>;

template < typename T >
concept IsA = Check< T, A >; 

template < typename T >
concept IsB = Check< T, B >; 


template < IsA T >
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "All A Types " <<   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template < IsB T >
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "All B Types " <<   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Func<A<int>>();
    Func<B<int>>();
    Func<C<int>>();
}
```

It feels a bit complicated to me. Can that be simplified? Would be nice if the `Check` template can be removed. Any idea?

See full example here [live](https://godbolt.org/z/cW8qWx7h5)

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what problem you're trying to solve? Are you trying to minimize template instantiations? Minimize lines of code?

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, would be nice to write some "instant" code directly in the functions template parameter... if possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It feels a bit complicated to me. Can that be simplified? Would be nice if the Check template can be removed. Any idea?

Much of complexity and in-elegance is in the fact you need a new concept for every class template. Write a general-purpose and reusable concept, and it is no longer complicated to use.

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class TT>
constexpr bool is_instantiation_of_v = false; 

template <template <typename...> class TT, typename... TS>
constexpr bool is_instantiation_of_v <TT<TS...>, TT> = true;

template <class C, template<typename...> class TT>
concept instantiation_of = is_instantiation_of_v<C, TT>;
```

The same principle as yours, except the checker is usable with a template taking any number of type arguments. Meanwhile, the concept accepts the same parameters. The first parameter has a special meaning and is implicitly understood to be the constrained template parameter in the short-hand syntax. The rest (the template template-parameter) must be given explicitly.

How can it be used? [Like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IDdSXekcqVHVYQoB)

```
template <instantiation_of<A> T>
int Func()
{
    return 'A';
}

template <instantiation_of<B> T>
int Func()
{
    return 'B';
}
```

Got a new class template to constrain over? No problem, this concept works without additional boiler-plate.

```
template <instantiation_of<D> T>
int Func()
{
    return 'D';
}
```

Comment: What would be the right way to specialize `Func` to, say, `int`?  I've tried to define `template <typename T> int Func()` and specialize it, but this fails in the context of friending (https://godbolt.org/z/x9dY7dPPT).  Moving the generic template *definition* down makes it work, although I'm unsure why (https://godbolt.org/z/6EfhhaT9r); using `same_as` makes it work but seems a bit clumsy (https://godbolt.org/z/xnx94181e).  Cheers!

Comment: @Michaël - If any C++ problem is X, which has a solution Y, then function template specialization is almost invariably Z. You can't partially specialize function templates. Your examples' (as well as the OP) interduces overloads. So you aren't befriending the same function you hope to constrain in the first example, and have no declaration visible to befriend in the second or third example.  
Also, the friendship with the specific specialization is potentially a non-starter, I can't say off the top of my head when the friend is instantiated, but it could very well be too early.

Comment: @Michaël - And speaking of overloading, pattern matching is almost always better when it comes to distinguishing overloads. https://godbolt.org/z/8zEq93vMT

Comment: Thanks a lot!  My goal was to have a default implementation available.  Putting it after the befriending works in GCC but not clang (https://godbolt.org/z/3a4aTdoMe), as you hinted, and putting it before the class befriends the wrong specialization.  Quite the conundrum !

Answer (score 5):

One common workaround would go like this:

```
template <typename T> 
struct FuncImpl {
  static void Run() { std::cout << "Default"; }
};

template <typename T> 
struct FuncImpl<A<T>> {
  static void Run() { std::cout << "Specialized for A<T>"; }
};

template <typename T>
void Func() { FuncImpl<T>::Run(); }
```

Function templates cannot be partially specialized, but class templates can be; so we just delegate from the former to the latter.

Answer (score 2):

OP writes:

> Yes, would be nice to write some "instant" code directly in the functions template parameter... if possible...

Normally, to determine whether it's a specialization of some given class template, we define a trait ahead of time and then check whether the type satisfies that trait. If you don't want to define anything ahead of time, you have to find a way to perform template argument deduction *inline*, so you can check whether it succeeds. In C++20, this is straightforward but a bit ugly:

```
template <typename T> 
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "unconstrained" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
requires requires {
    []<typename U>(const A<U>&){}(std::declval<T>());
}
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "constrained" << std::endl;
}
```

Here, the *requires-clause* checks whether `T` can be bound to an argument of type `const A<U>&` for some deducible `U`. You can see this example here: https://godbolt.org/z/dTEbaaPvh

This isn't exactly pleasant to read. If you will be using this hack multiple times, I think it's better to just define traits instead. I've answered your question simply to satisfy your curiosity, not to recommend this technique.

The version above will pick the constrained version not only when the template argument is some `A<U>` but also when it is possibly cv-qualified, possibly ref-qualified, and possibly publicly derived from `A<U>`. Some tweaks are possible to make the constraint more strict.

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain what is `[]<typename U>(const A<U>&){}(std::declval<T>());`. I see a lambda but the following `(std::declval<T>())` is quite unclear to me...

Comment: @Klaus `[]<typename U>(const A<U>&){}` is a lambda expression with an explicit template argument list. Following that, we attempt to call the lambda with a single argument, `std::declval<T>()`. This function generates a value of type `T&&` without needing to construct a `T`. It can only be called in an unevaluated context.

Comment: Arggg.. yeah! Simply call the lambda... :-) Where are my glasses... :-) Thanks!

Comment: @BrianBi Could you please add the other solution you commented (using a trait ahead of time)? Thanks!

Comment: @rturrado The OP already showed how to do it in the question.

Comment: @BrianBi Cool, thanks, I thought there may be a simpler solution.